# After alert focus on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Input Field and a button, after clicking on input field i am checking if input field is empty then prompt and alert box

- I am using `Jquery-conferm` to have some custom alert and conferm boxes
- but after the alert when i click on ok i am trying to focus on that field which is empty, but that's not working

**Snippet**

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  if ($('#itemNameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enter item name',

    });
    $('#itemNameInput').focus();

    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="itemName">Item Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNameInput" name="itemNameInput">
</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="update">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
```

I have written code for focusing back to input field but it not working

Comment: why dont you just use required in html?

Comment: @Harshit I am not using $("formId").submit thats why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is done by using  jquery-confirm action events

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  if ($('#itemNameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enter item name',
      onDestroy: function() {
        // here the button key 'hey' will be used as the text.
        $('#itemNameInput').focus();
      }
    });


    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="itemName">Item Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNameInput" name="itemNameInput">
</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="update">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One better option is to use sweet alerts, if you want to use only window alerts then try this,

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  if ($('#itemNameInput').val() == '') {
   
    if (window.confirm('Please enter item name'))
{
    
    $('#itemNameInput').focus();
}

    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="itemName">Item Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNameInput" name="itemNameInput">
</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="update">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
```

Comment: This one i am already doing.. i want to use some custom alert that's why i am trying to use `jquery-Conferm`

Answer (score 0):

I am applying setTimeout to give time to load parent DOM to focus on it.
I am using confirm box because on click of confirm, focus should be trigger.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#update").click(function() {
    if (!$('#itemNameInput').val()) {
      $.confirm({
        title: 'Alert!',
        content: 'Please enter item name',
        buttons: {
          confirm: {
            text: 'OK',
            btnClass: 'btn-red',
          }
        },
        onDestroy: function() {
          $('#itemNameInput').focus();
        },
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="itemName">Item Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNameInput" name="itemNameInput">
</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="update">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
```

Comment: hey why are you using timeout?

Comment: I have written explanation though

Comment: we can use own event of jquery-confirm,

Answer (score 0):

You can use confirm box with its onDestroy property

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  if ($('#itemNameInput').val() == '') {
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enter item name',
      buttons: {
        ok: function() {
        }
      },
      onDestroy:function(){$('#itemNameInput').focus();}
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="itemName">Item Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNameInput" name="itemNameInput">
</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="update">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery dialog https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message widget. But you need to have jquery ui for that.

You can define custom buttons and actions for each button. If the user press OK. Then you can set focus to desired control or perform desired action

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Just moved the `$('#itemNameInput').focus();` few lines up.

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  if ($('#itemNameInput').val() == '') {
    $('#itemNameInput').focus(); 
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enter item name',

    });
    

    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="itemName">Item Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNameInput" name="itemNameInput">
</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="update">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
```